The application cant be installed because it is incompatible with the device 0xC7D24FBC
Necesitamos implementar una aplicación con M365 Intune (MDM Kiosk) en una tablet. La tablet se registra correctamente, se detecta la aplicación, intenta instalarse y termina devolviendo este mensaje de error.
Encontré esta solución navegando por Internet, pero no consigo hacerla funcionar. ¡Gracias!
La tableta en la que estamos intentando instalar la aplicación no es compatible con
utiliza permiso call_phone.
elimine ese permiso en el manifiesto o intente agregar: <usos-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
Muchas Gracias,
Saludos.-

Agrega tu AndroidManfest.xml y comenta que sistema operativo usa el dispositivo en donde se presenta el problema.
